# How to display only last Record From data base in ado .net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, ado.net

store Procedure

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[Sp_User]
    (
    @Id int=null,
    @FullName varchar(50)=null,
    @Password varchar(50)=null,
    @Address varchar(100)=null,
    @Email varchar(50)=null,
    @Imgurl varchar(50)=null,
    @Activity varchar(50)=null
    )

    As Begin

    if(@Activity='Add')
    insert into registration
    (FullName,[Password],[Address],Email,Imgurl)
    values
    (@FullName,@Password,@Address,@Email,@Imgurl)


    if(@Activity = 'All')
    select top 1 FullName,Email,Password,imgurl from registration order by Id desc
    End
```

in User DAL

```
public List<User>All(ActivityMode a)
        {
            SqlConnection con = ConnectionDAL.SQL();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "Sp_User";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@activity", a.ToString());
            List<User> lst = null;
            con.Open();
            using (con)
            {
                SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (DR.HasRows)
                {
                    lst = new List<User>();
                    while (DR.Read())
                    {
                        User obj = new User();
                        obj.Id = Convert.ToInt32(DR["Id"]);
                        obj.FullName = DR["FullName"].ToString();
                        obj.Email = DR["Email"].ToString();
                        obj.Password = DR["Password"].ToString();
                        obj.Address = DR["Address"].ToString();
                        obj.Imgurl = DR["Imgurl"].ToString();
                        lst.Add(obj);
                    }
                }
            }
            return lst;
        }
```

in Conrloar

```
public ActionResult ViewAllUser()

        {
            RegisterHandler th = new RegisterHandler();
            List<User> lst = new List<User>();
            lst = th.All();

            return View(lst);
        }
```

I want to display only the last record.

I`m running the project and getting this error.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ID
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: ID
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 90: {
> Line 91: User obj = new User();
> Line 92: obj.Id = Convert.ToInt32(DR["ID"]);
> Line 93: obj.FullName = DR["FullName"].ToString();
> Line 94: obj.Email = DR["Email"].ToString();
> ```

How to resolve it? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you are seeing this error is the stored procedure is not selecting all the columns that you are trying to read, you need to ensure the select list here:

```
select top 1 FullName,Email,Password,imgurl from registration order by Id desc
```

contains all the columns that you are reading here:

```
User obj = new User();
obj.Id = Convert.ToInt32(DR["Id"]);
obj.FullName = DR["FullName"].ToString();
obj.Email = DR["Email"].ToString();
obj.Password = DR["Password"].ToString();
obj.Address = DR["Address"].ToString();
obj.Imgurl = DR["Imgurl"].ToString();
lst.Add(obj);
```

As an aside, I'd suggest  you create separate stored procedures to read and write data so that you can give independent permissions on them. You may also need to check for nulls on your reads

```
DR["<column>"]
```

Can result in DBNull.Value (if the column is nullable) as well as actual values and will error if you try and convert to an int in this case.
You may also want to consider why you're selecting the "last user" as in a multi-threaded environment you may see unexpected results if you rely on that being the one previously inserted for example.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Id Column in your Stored Procedure.

This is the correct sentence:
    select top 1 Id,FullName,Email,Password,imgurl from registration order by Id desc

Try this please.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are trying to get it when there is no ID in select statement.

In below statement add Id in select query like

```
if(@Activity = 'All')
    select top 1 Id, FullName,Email,Password,imgurl from registration order by Id desc
    End
```